# Are there potential issues with running multiple Wilcoxon tests by group?

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I'm interested in comparing 2 independent samples of data (by year) and found a very useful piece of code to "loop-through" the data by the group "year" in R, but want to make sure I understand the potential issues I'll run into by doing the analysis like this. The data are collected once a month at the same locations every year and I wish to compare months of values (not caring about the differences between years). There are 10 months in the full dataset over 18 years, but every test is only contrasting 2 months at a time (2 months in the same season, ex. April vs. March or June vs. July, etc).

My question is: Does running multiple Wilcoxon tests seem acceptable or do I run the risk of increasing the probability of a type 1 or 2 error? Are there other concerns I should worry about?

The goal of the study is to sample the same month each year, but sometimes we can't. We'd like to know if changing the month matters at all.

```
library(flexplot)
library(rstatix)

year1 <- rep(2010, 18)
year2 <- rep(2011, 18)
mar <- rep("March", 10)
apr <- rep("April", 8)

y <- as.data.frame(c(year1, year2))
m <- as.data.frame(c(mar, apr))

df0 <- cbind(y,m)

set.seed(123)
value <- runif(36, min=20, max=30)
  
alldata <- data.frame(df0, value)

names(alldata)[1] <- "year"
names(alldata)[2] <- "month"


flexplot(value ~ month | year, data = alldata)


diff <- by(alldata, alldata$year, function(z) wilcox.test(value ~ month, data = z))
names(diff)
diff


# Effect size
effect <- by(alldata, alldata$year, function(z) wilcox_effsize(value ~ month, data = z))
effect
```

Comment: Certainly the overall risk of at least one type I error will increase but whether the overall risk or the per-test risk is more of concern to you is not a question we can answer for you.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Although a glm would answer a slightly different question (is month as a factor important in predicting this “value”), would it lower that type 1 error risk? As an alternative to several Wilcoxon tests.

Comment: Which GLM did you have in mind as answering an equivalent collection of hypotheses to the Wilcoxon tests?

Comment: Perhaps a gamma glm? I don’t know how I would do the pair-wise comparisons, but I’ve read it’s fine for continuous and slightly skewed data. I’m not really sure of any equivalent, but I’m open to any advice towards an alternative method.

Comment: This looks like it will help as well: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233443/how-to-test-for-statistical-differences-between-sets-of-skewed-data

Comment: A gamma GLM is a model for a conditional mean, a Wilcoxon is not; so at least in that sense they're responding to different sorts of questions; if a GLM is a suitable choice - because the model responds to a question of interest, a Wilcoxon test might not be (depending on your actual hypotheses) -- and vice versa. I asked because I wasn't sure if you were aware of ordered logit models, which can be considered as a generalization of the Wilcoxon.

Comment: On the other hand if your hypotheses were so vague that you didn't see your hypothesis as even distinguishing between difference in means vs  P(X>Y),  well, okay -- but then I am curious how you deal with the fact that it's quite possible for them to shift in opposite directions at the same time: a difference in population means could go one direction while P(X>Y) could move in the opposite direction (in the sense that which group is seen as "higher" could be different for the two).

Comment: It may help to be very clear about the alternatives that are of interest (i.e. what, as specifically as possible, you originally wanted to find out)